# Adding Content to the top of a form Page

Tags: forms, 8

I just want to add an easily editable block of content to the top of a Form page in Drupal 8.

This can either be adding text to the form or adding the form to a content item, I don't mind.

What's the most straight forward way of doing this?

Comment: What kind of form? What will you do with the block of content?

Comment: Just a standard contact form.

Comment: What do you want to do with the text block?

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple block (`/block/add?destination=/admin/structure/block/block-content`) and make it appear on the form's page.

If you can not setup the necessary restrictions for the block to appear, you have to go for [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) (but this means programming your own module).